# Théorie de Fourier in Sontag`s book

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was reading Sontag`s In America and she mentions:
"La théorie de Fourier sur les douze passions radicales.."

What is this theorem about?

Comment: Perhaps you want [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) or [math.se]. This is a site for the computing software *Mathematica*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Charles Fourier, not Joseph Fourier. It a question about philosophy, not science, and not Mathematica at all.

Answer (score 2):

this is not about [Joseph Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joeseph_Fourier) (one of the ~10 greatest mathematicians),

but [Charles Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Fourier) (1772-1837), a philosophe and writer, that inspired Marx and Engels and many writers.